# Apps Script API errors on given ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, api

Has anyone gone through this API and has figured it out?
This is my third time trying to get this to work by following this guide

I am using the swift version of this guide.

[Google Apps Script Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/ios?ver=swift#prerequisites)

And it always give me the same errors.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let kKeychainItemName = "Google Apps Script Execution API"
    private let kClientID = "493692471278-3mf6bo212flgjopl06hrjfeepphe70h4.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    private let kScriptId = "Mj0RNm2ZtohFurieBLPwnxYAb4Jnnku4P"
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
    // resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
    private let scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

    private let service = GTLService() // error Use of unresolved identifier 'GTLService'


    let output = UITextView()

    // When the view loads, create necessary subviews
    // and initialize the Google Apps Script Execution API service
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        output.frame = view.bounds
        output.editable = false
        output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
        output.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight |
            UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
       // error***  Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two 'UIViewAutoresizing'      operands


        view.addSubview(output);
        // Error**Use of unresolved identifier 'GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch'
        if let auth = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(
            kKeychainItemName,
            clientID: kClientID,
            clientSecret: nil) {
                service.authorizer = auth
        }

    }

    // When the view appears, ensure that the Google Apps Script Execution API service is authorized
    // and perform API calls
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
            canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize where canAuth {
                callAppsScript()
        } else {
            presentViewController(
                createAuthController(),
                animated: true,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }

    // Calls an Apps Script function to list the folders in the user's
    // root Drive folder.
    func callAppsScript() {
        output.text = "Getting folders..."
        let baseUrl = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/\(kScriptId):run"
        let url = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(baseUrl, queryParameters: nil)
        // error ** Use of unresolved identifier 'GTLUtilities'
        // Create an execution request object.
        var request = GTLObject()   
      // Error** Use of unresolved identifier 'GTLObject'

        request.setJSONValue("getFoldersUnderRoot", forKey: "function")

        // Make the API request.
        service.fetchObjectByInsertingObject(request,
            forURL: url,
            delegate: self,
            didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:")
    }

    // Displays the retrieved folders returned by the Apps Script function.
    func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLServiceTicket,
        finishedWithObject object : GTLObject,
        error : NSError?) {
            if let error = error {
                // The API encountered a problem before the script
                // started executing.
                showAlert("The API returned the error: ",
                    message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let apiError = object.JSON["error"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                // The API executed, but the script returned an error.

                // Extract the first (and only) set of error details and cast as
                // a Dictionary. The values of this Dictionary are the script's
                // 'errorMessage' and 'errorType', and an array of stack trace
                // elements (which also need to be cast as Dictionaries).
                let details = apiError["details"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                var errMessage = String(
                    format:"Script error message: %@\n",
                    details[0]["errorMessage"] as! String)

                if let stacktrace =
                    details[0]["scriptStackTraceElements"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        // There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start
                        // executing.
                        for trace in stacktrace {
                            let f = trace["function"] as? String ?? "Unknown"
                            let num = trace["lineNumber"] as? Int ?? -1
                            errMessage += "\t\(f): \(num)\n"
                        }
                }

                // Set the output as the compiled error message.
                output.text = errMessage
            } else {
                // The result provided by the API needs to be cast into the
                // correct type, based upon what types the Apps Script function
                // returns. Here, the function returns an Apps Script Object with
                // String keys and values, so must be cast into a Dictionary
                // (folderSet).
                let response = object.JSON["response"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let folderSet = response["result"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                if folderSet.count == 0 {
                    output.text = "No folders returned!\n"
                } else {
                    var folderString = "Folders under your root folder:\n"
                    for (id, folder) in folderSet {
                        folderString += "\t\(folder) (\(id))\n"
                    }
                    output.text = folderString
                }
            }
    }

    // Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Apps Script Execution API
    private func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch {
   // Error** Use of undeclared type 'GTLServiceTicket'     let scopeString = " ".join(scopes) // Error*  'join' is unavailable: call the 'joinWithSeparator()' method on the sequence of elements
        return GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(
            scope: scopeString,
            clientID: kClientID,
            clientSecret: nil,
            keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName,
            delegate: self,
            finishedSelector: "viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:"
        )
    }

    // Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Google Apps Script Execution API
    // with the new credentials.
    func viewController(vc : UIViewController,
        finishedWithAuth authResult : GTMOAuth2Authentication, error : NSError?)
  // Error** Use of undeclared type 'GTMOAuth2Authentication' {

            if let error = error {
                service.authorizer = nil
                showAlert("Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            service.authorizer = authResult
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Helper for showing an alert
    func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertView(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            delegate: nil,
            cancelButtonTitle: "OK"
        )
        alert.show()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I find it hard to believe that google would make a guide and have it not work for the current version of xcode. It even says at the bottom of their guide that it was last updated February 2016.

Wanted to see if anyone has had any luck with following this guide in the past.

is there another swift guide for this google API?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What errors? the more information you give the more lightly you get an answer?

Comment: Well it tells me to copy and paste the View controller and it gives me errors. Assuming I did the steps right before this, would it be an issue due to conversion from objective-c to swift?

Answer (score 0):

1)Looks like you aren't getting the header files. You need a Bridging-Header.h. That step is omitted from the Quickstart; see the Google Drive Quickstart for the step you need to take.
2)You can just comment out the following line, it doesn't seem to be necessary.

```
output.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight |
    UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
```

3)Those changes will fix the compile problems. I found that after fixing the compile problems, it would not link and run on a phone. 
The Quickstart guide has you link the GTL.framework with your app using Xcode's 'Link Binary with Libraries'. I instead installed it using Cocoapods (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-API-Client) and was then able to run my app.